# Failed to configure Release Management

Tags: release, webdeploy, ms-release-management

I have a problem when i try to configure the agent on another server.

I have installed the Server RM in one machine and i use the user with name: usr_deploy.
(This machine has an domain called: mydomain.local)

I have another server that i need map to submit files for deploy. What i do? I installed the Agent RM, using the same account and password, but when i try to configure i have the error:
(This machine has an domain called: anotherdomain.local)

(Because i´m a new user i cant post image. I found the same image in Url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrkpQ.jpg)

All users i used with the name usr_deploy have local account on each server.

I need to use the same account but all the accounts needs to be a domain account ?

I have very difficultily to find on the web articles or steps to make the correctly configuration.

My scenario is 1 server with the RM Server and 3 servers to make a deploy.

Anyone can help me ?

Tks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a trust relationship between your domains, you'll have to use shadow accounts.

[MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/12/12/configuring-release-management-to-work-across-untrusted.aspx):

> Follow these steps to configure the Release Management Server and the
>   Deployment Agent on machines that run in different domains that do not
>   have a two-way trust relationship.
>
> 1. On each computer where you will install the RM Server or Deployment Agent, create a local user account that is a member of the
>      Administrators group. Use the same account and password on each
>      machine (i.e. Shadow Account).
> 2. Add the RM Server’s Shadow Account to RM and grant both “Service User” and “Release Manager” permissions.
> 3. Add the Deployment Agent’s Shadow Account to RM and grant “Service User” permission.
> 4. Use the Shadow Account as the service account when you install and configure the Deployment Agent.
>
>    Note: When you add the local accounts to Release Management, include
>      the name of the local machine where the account resides. For example,
>      add the user account as \ or

Answer (score 0):

When you are configuring the shadow account as the service account in deployment agent, make sure that you logged in using the same shadow account.

Answer (score 0):

write it down as

Correct way:- http://(server):(port)

Incorrect way:- http://(server):(port)/ReleaseManagement

Do not write "/ReleaseManagement/" or any other URL segments after . This will solve your problem.

for e.g. : 
http://sunnyserver:1000

Comment: first make sure that the name that is in Release Management Server is same as the server name in deployement agent